# How to overwrite my database when updated

Tags: android, database

i m stroring in a database some news that i get from rss.My problem is that i want the new feed to overwrite the old one.I want everytime to have 10 news in my database,but now i m having every time i refresh 10 more..

Searching the net i found that the solution must be the `onUpgrade` method.Could you help me to do that?this is the onUpgrade i m using as now:

```
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    android.util.Log.w("Constants",
            "Upgrading database, which will destroy all data"); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myDB");
    onCreate(db);

}
```

EDIT

```
public void createEntry(String string,String string2,String string3,String string4,String string5){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBHelper.TITLE, string);
    cv.put(DBHelper.AGONISTIKI, string2);
    cv.put(DBHelper.SKOR, string3);
    cv.put(DBHelper.GIPEDO, string4);
    cv.put(DBHelper.DATE, string5);
    try
    {
        ourDatabase.insert("osfpDB",null,cv);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR ON .INSERT", e.toString()); // prints the error message to the log
        e.printStackTrace(); // prints the stack trace to the log
    }

}
public void update(String string,String string2,String string3,String string4,String string5){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBHelper.TITLE, string);
    cv.put(DBHelper.AGONISTIKI, string2);
    cv.put(DBHelper.SKOR, string3);
    cv.put(DBHelper.GIPEDO, string4);
    cv.put(DBHelper.DATE, string5);
    try
    {
        ourDatabase.update("osfpDB",cv,DBHelper.ROWID,null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR ON .UPDATE", e.toString()); // prints the error message to the log
        e.printStackTrace(); // prints the stack trace to the log
    }

}
```

AND

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> List_agones = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(messages.size());
            for (Message2 msg : messages){

                des.add(msg.getDescription());//keimeno
                SK.add(msg.getskor());
                GOALA.add(msg.getgoal1());
                GOALB.add(msg.getgoal2());
                TITLES.add(msg.getTitle());
                AGONISTIKI.add(msg.getagonistiki());


                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("agon", msg.getagonistiki());

                map.put("name", msg.getTitle());
                map.put("date", msg.getDate());
                map.put("gip", msg.getgipedo());

                map.put("SK", msg.getskor());

               List_agones.add(map);

                ListAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, List_agones, R.layout.agonesrow,
                            new String[] {"agon","name", "date","gip", "SK"}, new int[] {R.id.TextView00,R.id.TextView01, R.id.TextView02, R.id.TextView04, R.id.TextView03});
                this.setListAdapter(mSchedule);


                //grafei stin vasi dedomenwn
                //-------------------------
                HotOrNot entry=new HotOrNot(agones.this);

                   entry.open();
                   if(map== null){

                       Toast.makeText(agones.this, "1",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      entry.createEntry(msg.getTitle(),msg.getagonistiki(),msg.getskor(),msg.getgipedo(),msg.getDate());
                   }else{

                       Toast.makeText(agones.this, "2",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      entry.update(msg.getTitle(),msg.getagonistiki(),msg.getskor(),msg.getgipedo(),msg.getDate());
                   }

                   entry.close();
                //----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

onUpgrade is called when a user updates versions of your application and database and handles porting the data from the old DB version to the new one.  You can use the SqlLiteDatabase class to call insert, update, and delete on the records in your db.  So you'd have to say something like this:

```
if NumberOfRecords == 10
   delete oldest recodr
insert new record
```

You can see an implementation of the insert, update and delete methods here http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html.

Comment: i have tried the way of your link but i have stacked somewhere.Could we have a chat?

Comment: Can you post the code that is failing for you?  Not sure when I'll be available for a chat but I'll try if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete and recreate the database for new feeds. just update the 10 rows you have in your database.

EDIT:

I am working now got not much time to go over the details
what you should do is something like ( i only added the row id ), where rowId is 1 to 10.

```
public void update(String string,String string2,String string3,String string4,String string5, rowId){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBHelper.TITLE, string);
    cv.put(DBHelper.AGONISTIKI, string2);
    cv.put(DBHelper.SKOR, string3);
    cv.put(DBHelper.GIPEDO, string4);
    cv.put(DBHelper.DATE, string5);
    try
    {
        ourDatabase.update("osfpDB",cv,rowId,null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR ON .UPDATE", e.toString()); // prints the error message to the log
        e.printStackTrace(); // prints the stack trace to the log
    }

}
```

so you pass in the row id that you want to update everytime. in the loop. create a counter with the row id eg:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
     update(string1, string2, string 3 /*blah blah blah*/, i);
}
```

. to do the update for u.

Another thing to take note is when you are creating your database, insert a dummy data of 10 rows. the 10 rows (or w/e number of rows you need) should be there before you do any update. if the record doesn't exist. the update will fail. will take a deeper look at your code after work. sorry.

EDIT:

Ok. something like this. but i dont see what is the use of your createEntry. mind showing the code or explaining? like i said. insert 10 empty rows and do the update on them. Laters.

```
 int rowId = 1;
 for (Message2 msg : messages){

            des.add(msg.getDescription());//keimeno
            SK.add(msg.getskor());
            GOALA.add(msg.getgoal1());
            GOALB.add(msg.getgoal2());
            TITLES.add(msg.getTitle());
            AGONISTIKI.add(msg.getagonistiki());


             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("agon", msg.getagonistiki());

            map.put("name", msg.getTitle());
            map.put("date", msg.getDate());
            map.put("gip", msg.getgipedo());

            map.put("SK", msg.getskor());

           List_agones.add(map);

            ListAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, List_agones, R.layout.agonesrow,
                        new String[] {"agon","name", "date","gip", "SK"}, new int[] {R.id.TextView00,R.id.TextView01, R.id.TextView02, R.id.TextView04, R.id.TextView03});
            this.setListAdapter(mSchedule);


            //grafei stin vasi dedomenwn
            //-------------------------
            HotOrNot entry=new HotOrNot(agones.this);

               entry.open();
               if(map== null){

                   Toast.makeText(agones.this, "1",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  entry.createEntry(msg.getTitle(),msg.getagonistiki(),msg.getskor(),msg.getgipedo(),msg.getDate());
               }else{

                   Toast.makeText(agones.this, "2",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  entry.update(msg.getTitle(),msg.getagonistiki(),msg.getskor(),msg.getgipedo(),msg.getDate(), rowId++);
               }

               entry.close();
            //----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Look at the link in the other answer.  It should explain how to do updates and deletes to your database.

Comment: Can you show the basic structure of the table? then we should be able to help you construct one.

Comment: @Rejinderi I have reedited my answer with parts of my code!Is that ok?

Comment: @kgr are you getting an error when you try to do an update?  Also, do you have code to delete the records once you go over 10?

Comment: my app has some scores from football matches of a greek team.There are 30 matches and i get every week a new score.If the user has wifi then he can see the score from my server.But if there is no wifi connection i want to save the data into a database and see them offline.When the user starts the app,he can see the comming matches but instead o score there is a - if the match hasnt done yet.When we have a new score i replace the - with the score.So i want to have every time 30 rows and just update the -.

Comment: With the code i use,every time i add 30 more rows in my database with the same data.I want to replace the old 30 rows with the new 30!Thats my problem

Comment: so,in order to answer your question,i have no error,just add more rows in database,and i have no more code for it